# Do I have to click on the screen to play sound? How to auto active the sound after the page has loaded completely?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5-audio, autoplay

I have a timer with counting sound effects. However it works only if I can click on the screen before the timer has been triggered. I have tried body trigger onClick event but with no luck. Any suggestions? thanks.

HTML

```
<audio controls id="soundCount" class="d-none embed-responsive-item">
<source src="counting.mp3" type="audio/mp3">Your browser does not support the <code>audio</code> element.
</audio>
```

JS

```
function playSoundCount() {
    document.getElementById("soundCount").load();
    document.getElementById("soundCount").play();
}

function timer() {
    var counter = 10;
    var interval = setInterval(function() {
        counter--;
        if (counter <= 0) {
            clearInterval(interval);
            return;
        }
        else if(counter <= 10){
            playSoundCount()
        }
        else{
            console.log(Math.floor(counter));
        }
    }, 1000);
}
```

Comment: This is a feature of modern browsers. Audio will only be played if the user has first interacted with the page in some manner (mouse click, typing etc). You cannot play a sound before the interaction has occurred.

Comment: What Rory said. But - If you use PWA the sounds will not be muted: https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Thanks mate, I will have look at it ASAP.